# How to: Mybatis query term with a single quote / apostrophe

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a search page that uses the user's entered term to query the database.  Im using Mybatis 3.4.0 with Spring.

The problem is that Mybatis is stripping out any single quotes in the search term, whether I escape them or not.  These are valid queries, since the user needs to be able to search for strings like O'Toole,  but nothing is being returned.

Here is a snippet of the code from the mapper.  The field in question is `caseWhereConditionDTO.value`   and the incoming value is, for example,  `O''TOOLE` (manually escaped prior in code)

```
<if test="caseWhereConditionDTO.value != null">
    ${caseWhereConditionDTO.leftExpression}
    ${caseWhereConditionDTO.operator} 
    #{caseWhereConditionDTO.value}
    ${caseWhereConditionDTO.closeConditionString}
</if>
```

which results in the where clause

```
where  UPPER(p.last_name ||', ' || p.first_name ) LIKE 'OTOOLE%'
```

which is missing the double escaped O''TOOLE

Everything works fine when in the mapper I replace the # with $ and surround with single quotes

```
'${caseWhereConditionDTO.value}'
```

resulting in a sql output of

```
where  UPPER(p.last_name ||', ' || p.first_name ) LIKE 'O''TOOLE%'
```

which gives the expected query results

but of course I would like to preserve the sql injection protection of the #{}

So my question is,  how do I  query for terms with single quotes while still using the sql injection protection of the #{} / prepared statement?

Comment: If you're already manually escaping caseWhereConditionDTO.value with double quotes, could you possibly use a text literal syntax instead? For example, look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344, and work to generate your where clause like  where q'[UPPER (p.last_name ||' , ', ' || p.first_name ) like 'O'TOOLE%']'

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options where there is no need to escape single quotes:

- Unless it is certain that input will not contain any `%` they must be escaped first (if they exist in the input and are not escaped, it would create confusion for SQL: is `%` part of input or an "*operator*"?) then concatenate the `%` to the value : `value = value + "%";` and then `LIKE #{value}`.
- The better option is just to concatenate the `%` in the SQL query: `LIKE #{value} || '%'`. It does work, I have just rechecked it.

Comment: Im not sure I follow,  the problem isnt the  `% `,  its the `' '` that is getting stripped out

Comment: edited answer: quotes does not require escaping, whereas `%` could.

Comment: I see now,  yes I am concatenating the % separately,  in my mapper snippet,  thats the ' ${caseWhereConditionDTO.closeConditionString}'  which is the %.      could you go into more detail on quotes not needing escaping?  mybatis strips out quotes whether i escape them or not

Comment: _quotes not needing escaping_ : means do not apply prior processing on your value, pass it as is. Furthermore, forget the 1st option I proposed, use 2nd: do not concatenate in java/mybatis, do in SQL, that means `caseWhereConditionDTO.closeConditionString="|| '%'"`